# Is there a way ito iterate the list of files from aws s3 bucket in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, amazon-s3

I am using shell scripting and I want to get the list of files from AWS S3 bucket, and then perform a for loop based on the number of files present in list object.

Here is my code to get the files from S3 bucket in shell script:

```
S3_files=$(aws s3 ls s3://s3_bucket_path/ | awk '{print $4}')
```

`S3_files` variable take the list of files as a whole string, so not able to iterate using the loop. The loop runs just onetime as it considers the list of files as a string, and jut run one time. Below is my code:

```
for i in "${S3_files[@]}"
do
{
  echo "$i"
}
done
```

So, I want to understand how we can iterate it using the loop based on the total number of files.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `S3_Files=( $(aws ... ) )` . If the filenames have whitespace chars embedded, then this won't work either. Good luck.

Comment: FYI, if you just want filenames, you use: `aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query Contents[].[Key] --output text`